# Displaying multilookup result as a table in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, report, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to build a report (in Report Builder 3.0) to produce a per-PC action sheet for an upcoming PC rollout. I have two Datasets - one with a range of fields about the PC (`Dset1`) and another that identifies all the software installed on a PC (`Dset2`).

`Dset1` looks like this:

[image: Dataset 1]

The aim is to produce a report that has a range of fields from `Dset1` at the top followed by a list of rows from `Dset2` where `DSet2.Computer_Name = Dset1.Current_PC_Name`.

I've got the first half worked out which looks like this:

[image: Report Design]

But I cannot work out how to report on the installed software below the section shown. I've looked into using Multilookup and lookupset but can't wrap my head around how these functions work.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how I can get the desired outcome?

Comment: If you will only be running this report for one computer at a time you will want to look at inserting a tablix. If you will be running this report for many computers at a time you will want to look at using a sub-report.

Comment: Thanks, the intention is to be able to run it on groups of computers, and that is how the report I've built so far works.  I'll look into inserting a sub-report.

Comment: Many thanks, I managed to get my report working the way I wanted with the use of a subreport.